# В каком контейнере лучше хранить число, большее чем long?

Tags: java, math

У меня задача - уложить в какой-либо контейнер 30-ти значное число, что уже по определению больше чем Long.MAX, которое всего 19-ти разрядное. А нужно это для того, чтобы потом от этого числа, до такого же многозначного числа запустить цикл, проходящий все промежуточные значения.

Есть ли идеи в чём лучше хранить многозначное число и как его инкрементировать с минимальными потерями по памяти и операциям?

P.S. Пока разместил в ArrayList , но вот как его разумнее увеличивать пока идей нет

Comment: а разница между ними больше чем long?

Comment: @Komdosh Да, конечно. Разница между ними может быть гораздо больше long. Я уже думал над таким вариантом ;)

Comment: Как насчёт `BigInteger` (для целых) или `BigDecimal` (для десятичных дробей)?

Comment: у меня есть сомнения, что цикл, проходящий все значения в интервале "больше чем long", завершится за разумное время.

Comment: @zRrr И при этом, Ваши сомнения совершенно оправданы, однако это условие задачи, и оно не является предметом обсуждения. Однако, если у Вас имеются идеи как сделать это оптимальнее, то я охотно их выслушаю.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Раз разница больше чем `long`, то вам необходимо воспользоваться классом `Biginteger`, он динамически выделяет столько памяти, сколько необходимо.

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("832661234732141234321");
```